# Maintaining focus on textbox while I click on different buttons

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am currently trying to develop a custom keyboard for WinCE application.Currently I have a form with a text box and a button. The issue is how can I maintain the focus on the keyboard when I click on the mouse to SendInput (to make sure that the textbox capture that input). One way is to set the "Focusable" property but I can't seem to set that on a Windows Form. I hope someone could help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: In each method that links to a control try `textbox.Focus();`

Comment: Anyone who has worked with CE would immediately know what this question is asking, more evidence is not needed.  They're making the novice mistake of not creating an actual SIP and the focus is fighting them.  This is a completely valid question as it stands (and why can't I vote to re-open?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `TextBox.Focus()` on the button press event handler. I assume the button has a `KeyPress` or `KeyDown` function.

A more flexible alternative would be to store the last focused control.

```
private Control lastFocusedControl;
```

And when the text box is focused on it sets the value using the `GotFocus` event.

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lastFocusedControl = (Control)sender;
}
```

And then in the event handler you can simply do.

```
lastFocusedControl.Focus();
```

Comment: This is one possible way, however, I want to make my custom keyboard class portable, meaning it can be used in any windows form I developed. So if can, I don't want to hard code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not afraid of moving to the native side you may consider to implement a Software Input Panel (SIP). It will behave in the way you describe and can be used by any application running on the device.
This documentation is for Compact 2013, but it's also valid for previous releases (you can find release-specific versions on MSDN but they were pretty good in hiding them):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee500563.aspx

Comment: There is a SIP control in the WinCE of my device, but the size is too small. I've searched for the possibility to resize the SIP, and it seems that SetImInfo controls the layout of the SIP, so by invoking this method, I can change the size of it in my application?Correct me if I am wrong, thanks.

Comment: Valter is recommending creating a new, larger SIP that meets your needs, not changing the one that's there.

Comment: Ah...i see. I am still looking into several alternatives, as there are  some limitation (in my company) that are preventing me from developing in my own way. I have considered my question in this post answered, but I think the other suggestions given serve as a good example for developing custom keyboard for WinCE application, especially on the older version.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is for VB.Net it has some good ideas: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708756.aspx

See WS_EX_NOACTIVATE and

```
If (m.Msg = WM_MOUSEACTIVATE) Then
  m.Result = MA_NOACTIVATE
Else
  MyBase.WndProc(m)
End If
```

Now the challenge is to adopt this to your idea (a separate process and form? or a panel with buttons?).

OTOS MS provides a custom keyboard SDK API set to write custom software keyboards for Windows Mobile (c/C++).

Comment: That is a good reference, thanks. However, I can't seem to find OTOS MS,what does it stand for?I am bind to C# for the development due to certain reason, but I would still like to check it out.

Comment: MS stands for Microsoft and the API and example I am talking about is the dvorak software input panel: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158734.aspx